# Reading property of element / array

Tags: javascript

Good day! I am not exactly sure what is wrong with this code. It is supposed to change the background image of the div every N seconds and loop through the array. Thanks in advance

```
window.setInterval(foo(), 400);
//
var arr = [
    "img1.jpg",
    "img2.jpg",
    "img3.jpg"
];

//Set up variables
var waitTime = 5;
var main = document.getElementById("main");
var i = 0;

function foo() {
    main.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + arr[i] + ")";
    if (i > arr.length) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.setInterval(foo(), 400);
```

This calls `foo` and sets nothing to run every 400 milliseconds.

```
window.setInterval(foo, 400);
```

This sets `foo` to run every 400 milliseconds.

```
setInterval(foo, 400);
```

This does that also.

Finally, this:

```
if (i > arr.length) {
```

should use `>=` or `===`.